# Webview string limit and showing "&" when targetSdkVersion 29

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've built apps, fetching JSON from WordPress using rest API and showing that all string to webview.

It's works perfectly in targetSdkVersion 28.
but when upgrading to targetSdkVersion 29 the string looks like auto excerpt and giving symbols "&" in the end text.

Exp : Horse is animals, have 4 legs and one head (normal string using targetSdkVersion 28)
Exp : Horse is animals, have 4 legs an& (like giving limit or excerpt using targetSdkVersion 29)

See my picture, please.

Normal using targetSdkVersion 28:

[image]

Error string and showing Symbols "&" using targetSdkVersion 29:

[image]

Comment: It might be helpful to post some of your code.

Comment: I can't put code because i dont know, where my mistake .. The log is success without any problem..

Comment: Thank for editing and review my post :D